# Wrong resolution or size of display

Tags: display, screen

After last reboot I have a problem with wrong resolution of display:
[image: screen shot]

If I take a screenshot with shortcut I have whole display:
[image: full screen shot]

Last time a reboot helped, but the 3rd time. I've disabled programs launched at login, does not help. The screen size during boot is proper.
This happens on the display itself as well as when an additional monitor is connected.

MacOS: 12.6.1 Monterey.

Comment: What happens if you push the cursor against the right hand side - does the displayed content move with you?

Comment: Yes. The content move after cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have toggled the Accessibility Zoom on by accident.

Check the Control Panel to see what key combo or scroll action may have triggered it. I'm not sure mine is set to system defaults, so you might find slightly different settings to this…

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. But why? A shortcut was sent during login?

Comment: I've actually never tested it as to how early it can be triggered or if it survives reboot - but my partner toggles it often by accident then asks me every time what just happened … so I'm kind of used to how it looks ;)